# Managing AVSpeechSynthesizer's execution via system playback controls

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession, avspeechsynthesizer, control-center

Is there any way to make AVSpeechSynthesizer's execution be manageable via system playback controls in control centre panel? Now I can change the volume, but pause button is not responsive, and next/prev buttons are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a while I found the answer. If somebody else is interested there is MPRemoteCommandCenter class which does the business. Enjoy your coding.